# How to understand this generic interface definition in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Does the definition of this `Cache` type, `Cache<V = any>`, define an object or a function?

Here the generic `V`, why specify an `any`? What does the equals sign mean?

```js
export interface Cache<V = any> {
  value?: V;
  timeoutId?: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>;
  time?: number;
  alive?: number;
}
```

Comment: The equals sign makes type parameter `V` optional, so that both `Cache` and `Cache<SomeType>` usage is possible

Answer (score 1):

`Cache` defines an object here.
`V = any` means that `V` is of type `any` if no generic `value` is provided, and the value in this object is also of type `any`.
The equal sign here means the default value.

Comment: This doesn't seem to correspond **at all** with the question, it's unclear to me why it's been upvoted or accepted by @Larry.

Comment: Sorry, when I edited the answer to another question, I changed a question wrong